# Making one of the field in Solr (URL)hyperlink

Tags: java, servlets, solr, solrj

What I mean is, when the user search a particular stuff, for instance Supreme,

It will print out **supremenewyork.com** , Supreme, A skateboarding shop/clothing brand[1][2] established in New York City in April 1994.

How do I make the text **supremenewyork.com** become an URL. Basically I get the parameter from servlet and printed on a JSP result page. Based by what I know it cannot be done in the Solr side.

Any expert in Solr able to give me a solution?

Below is my following code.

```
        System.out.println("request parameter: "
                + request.getParameter("search"));
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/Corename/");
            SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
            String test;

            // Getting the parameter from the textbox name search
            query.setQuery(request.getParameter("search"));


            query.setFields("id", "content");
            query.setStart(0);

            QueryResponse response1 = solr.query(query);
            SolrDocumentList results = response1.getResults();
            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {

                test = results.toString();
                String testresults = test.replace("numFound=2,start=0,docs=[","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("numFound=1,start=0,docs=[","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("numFound=4,start=0,docs=[","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("SolrDocument{", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("content=[", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("id=", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("]}]}", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("]}", "");



                request.setAttribute("testresults", testresults);
                System.out.println(testresults);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Results.jsp").forward(request,
                        response);

            }
        } catch (SolrServerException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**JSP Code:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>THE SUPER SEARCH</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Here's the following results</h4>
<%String testresults=(String)request.getAttribute("testresults");
out.print("" + testresults);
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you printing out the values now? Are they separate fields in the document? Do you need to identify the URL inside an existing field and add a link around it, or can you use `<a href="${doc.url}">${doc.url}</a>` directly?

Comment: Basically I get parameter from the servlet, and then print in JSP. And yea they are separate fields but when I retrieved it from Solr I call the parameter "testresults" I just edited my question you can take a look at my code. Sorry I am not really good at explaining code. @MatsLindh

Answer (score 1):

I discourage to do this thing directly in Solr, IMHO it is like to ask MySql to store a string and return a url.

Anyway, if you really want do this with Solr, there are many ways:

1. use [Solr DocTransformers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents)
2. format the output of one or more fields, I suggest to use [XSLTResponseWriter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Response+Writers#ResponseWriters-TheXSLTResponseWriter) which can return also json.
3. add to your Solr instance your own SearchComponent, here is an [interesting post](http://sujitpal.blogspot.it/2011/04/custom-solr-search-components-2-dev.html) and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/searchbox-com/tutorial-on-developin-a-solr-search-component-plugin).
4. another way I know is [Alba](https://github.com/leonardofoderaro/alba/wiki/Adding-the-book-cover), Solr Plugins made easy.

At last, if you really want have back a ulr, you could just store the url in a field during the indexing.

**UPDATE**

Looking at code you have posted, the biggest problem I see is the way you're using to iterate on the returned results set. You should do something like this:

```
for (SolrDocument d : response1.getResults()) {
    String content = (String) d.get("content");
    long id = (long) d.get("id");
}
```

A `Solrdocument` internally is a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and solution. Anyway if I don't want to do on Solr and want to do on the client/UI side. Is there any solution to it? Basically I already changed the "testresults" which is suppose the query from Solr to string already.

Comment: Able to use regex? As I already changed the query to String. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Cedric.L take a look at the answer update.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. I already tried to apply the code but probably I applied it wrong and it give me this error "HTTP Status 500 - java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String" Able to show me how do I applied it? Really sorry about that if it is troublesome. @freedev

Comment: Probably it's because you're handling a multivalue field. First take a look at your `schema.xml` just to understand what's kind of fields you're handling. If, as I suppose, you have a multivalue field instead of `.get` method, try using `getFieldValues` which returns an `List`, may be a `List<String>` in your case, or try `getFirstValue`. And in any case read this, SolrDocument docs: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocument.html

Comment: And remember to upvote this and all the answers you find useful.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. Basically I found a much more simple method. I separated the two queries(As I have change the query to string) and set 2 attributes and then I follow the answer here!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060034/set-string-to-clickable-url

Comment: Sorry, as I am new to programming much more difficult method will be very challenging for me! But still thank you so much for helping me! @freedev