# Set String to clickable URL

Tags: java, html, string, jsp, setattribute

Am I able to change one the attribute from normal text become an URL(hyperlink) so user will be able to click on it and redirect to another page.

Basically the **attribute that I get from servlet** is www.stackoverflow.com but is in **plain text so my question is how do I change it to a clickable link**?

Any expert out there know how to set it? Thank you so much and have a nice day!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2nd.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>THE SUPER SEARCH</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Here's the following results</h4>
        <%
            String testresults=(String)request.getAttribute("testresults");
            out.print("" + testresults);
        %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <% 
            String testcontent=(String)request.getAttribute("testcontent");
            out.print("" + testcontent);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside an `<a>` tag.
Something like

```html
<a href="<%=testresults%>"><%=testresults%></a>
```

Regards

Comment: At String testresults=(String)request.getAttribute("testresults"); ? or the outprint line? Sorry really a newbie to this stuff. @Oldskultxo

Comment: Sorry take a look now, im on mobile. You have to set the value of href attribute on html a tag.

Comment: Thank you so much, have a nice day! @Oldskultxo